# Will this approach protect my database from being modified?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

All I care about is my database not being altered. I don't have any login or stuff like that so I don't care about account bypassing, I just don't want people to be able to send commands like DROP through this simple HTML form.

Is this correct? It's what I came up after reading another related topic here.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO request_song (ip, mesaj, name, oras, pentru, song) VALUES (:ip, :mesaj, :name, :oras, :pentru, :song)");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
$stmt->bindParam(':mesaj', $message);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':oras', $oras);
$stmt->bindParam(':pentru', $pentru);
$stmt->bindParam(':song', $melodie);
$stmt->execute();
```

Will this fix any potential exploits? [This is the form](http://piratefm.ro/dedicatii.php) - can any white hats confirm it's safe please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be asking if your prepared query code will prevent SQL injection attacks.  If that is what you are asking, then yes.  Properly used prepared/parameterized queries separate the query (command) from the data.  SQL injection attacks work because data is sometimes blindly mixed with the command, allowing someone to control your server via data inputs.  Since they are separated in your case, this is not an issue.

> Will this fix any potential exploits?

No, and that would be impossible to answer as "yes" anyway.  That's a very broad question.  You still need to worry about all the other dangers.  Don't forget about XSS attacks and what not in the rest of your application.

Comment: XSS is really unrelated.

Comment: I'm strictly asking about any vulnerabilities that would lead to the database being compromised. As there are no users, what is there to hack with XSS? There's just data there, could call them logs, there's only one password to delete them by id, but the password is checked by md5 and is hardcoded into the site, not in the database.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Obviously.  He said, "will this fix any potential exploits", and I am trying to be clear that that is a very broad thing to ask.  So many folks think that because they fix one problem, that they are magically safe from everything.

Comment: @AronH. I have no idea what your application does.  Your question was very broad.  I just wanted to be clear so that you understand that there could be other issues that you haven't asked about.

Comment: I just think there is a lot of confusion and misinformation about what XSS is, how it works, and how to prevent it so I thought it was worth mentioning. People often think it is an *input* problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you really worried about it, then the easiest way to do it is that the `username/password` for `MySQL` that you use to connecting to the `MySQL database` should only have `Create, Read, Update access`. While granting privileges to the user, just make sure you select only the actions that you want.

When a user tries to delete a record, you can just set a flag for deletion, a "soft" delete. For all intentions for the user this record is non-existant, even if it is still in the database. Later purge the database of such records using another MySQL account that has Delete/Drop capability as well.

Comment: `DELETE FROM` is usually just as unsafe as `DROP`, and there might be plenty of cases where a `DELETE` is necessary.  While I agree a good practice is to only allow the access that is needed, there are plenty of cases where the required access can still lead to danger.

Comment: @Brad I agree, but it is always better if the database is that important to make sure that the user only has limited access to it even at a DB level. I once worked on a trading platform where no physical deletes happened, instead when the user deleted a record only a flag was set that it was deleted. And then we had another script that purged such records periodically. And of course that was using a different MySQL user account.

Comment: Rather than a boolean flag, use a timestamp `deleted_at` column, which is `NULL` when not deleted. You can then easily properly delete things that are X weeks old, for example. +1

Comment: @halfer - totally agree, Good tip!